Sums of Matrices; 2-Color an $m \times k$ grid so that no $2 \times 2$ squares of the same color occur
I want to determine the number of ways to uniquely 2-color an $m \times k$ grid such that no $2\times 2$ squares of the same color occur. The strategy I am trying right now is to assign each possible column/row of Black/White a unit vector. For example, $$\begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{White} \\ \vdots \\ \text{White}\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
where in this case there would need to be $2^m$ unit vectors. Then, I can determine which columns/rows can be placed next to it. This determines the matrix which, when summed, counts the number of legal grids.
Let me define the Sum of a matrix as follows:
$$\text{Sum}(A) = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}$$
In other words,
$$\text{Sum}(A) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \end{bmatrix} A\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
I have a procedure for generating the matrices $\{M_1, M_2, M_3, ...\}$ where $M_1$ is $2 \times 2, M_2$ is $4 \times 4, M_3$ is $ 8 \times 8,$ and in general $M_n$ is $2^n \times 2^n.$
I want to determine $\text{Sum}(M_n^k)$ for an arbitrary $n, k$ A recurrence relation would also be useful; that is, something like: $\text{Sum}(M_n^k) = f(\text{Sum}(M_{n-1}^k), \text{Sum}(M_{n-2}^k), ... ).$
The procedure:
Start with $M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Given $M_n$ it forms a block matrix:
$$M_{n} = \begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ B & A\end{bmatrix}$$
Now form the new block matrix $M_{n+1}$ as follows:
$$M_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\ B & A\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}B & A\\ A & B\end{bmatrix}\\ \begin{bmatrix}B & A\\ A & B\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\ B & A\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}A' & B'\\ B' & A'\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can follow this procedure to produce the first few matrices:
$$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}& \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
By the spectral theorem, diagonlization should work for any individual $M_n$ to find $M_n^k$ We determine the first two Sums:
$$\text{Sum}(M_1^k) = 2^{k+1}$$
$$\text{Sum}(M_2^k) = 2^{1-k}\left[(1-\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}})(3 - \sqrt{17})^k +(1+\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}})(3 + \sqrt{17})^k  \right]$$
Attempt:
So far, the only potentially useful idea I have is to use the fact that:
$M_{n+1}^k = \begin{bmatrix}A' & B'\\ B' & A'\end{bmatrix}^k = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}(A'+ B')^k +(A' - B')^k & (A'+ B')^k -(A' - B')^k \\ (A'+ B')^k -(A' - B')^k & (A'+ B')^k +(A' - B')^k\end{bmatrix}.$
So $$\text{Sum}( M_{n+1}^k) = 2(A'+ B')^k = 2 \text{Sum}(\begin{bmatrix}B & A+B \\ A+B & A+B\end{bmatrix}^k)$$
Compared to $$\text{Sum}( M_{n}^k)=2(A+ B)^k$$
It is possible that the regular formula for diagonlization of matrix with real numbers could be used here, but I am not sure how to make it work for block matrices. It may also be useful to just try to determine the general form of $M_{n}^k$ without having to use the iterative procedure. Because swapping the labeling of the unit vectors does not affect the final sum, one might be able to put the matrix into a more convenient form/simple shape by doing so, and then by induction show that this more convenient shape is always what the matrix looks like.
For $M_3$ then we have
$$\text{sum}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}^k = \text{sum}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^k$$
This smaller matrix corresponds to the grouping of the possible columns by the group operation of "inversion":
$$\{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix} \}, \{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix} \}, \{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix} \}, \{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix} \}$$
There is also another group operation which can be considered, rotation by 180 degrees, or equivalently a "reflection." The product we are interested in in that case is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^k \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
With groupings:
$$\{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix} \}, \{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix} \}, \{ \begin{pmatrix} \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \text{Black} \\ \text{White} \\ \text{Black} \end{pmatrix} \}$$
The $m=4$ matrix which takes into account symmetries is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^k\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 2  \end{pmatrix}
$$
